# How to distinguish between search or browse function?

Tags: php, html, forms, search, button

I've got a database with a couple of thousands entries. So I need a page to make some a simple search. I've been fiddling around with a simple form and search field, but I can't wrap my head around to distinguish wether a user has submitted a search query or pressed the browse button.

This is my simple HTML:

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
  <input autofocus name="query" placeholder="Enter your search here..." type="search" />
  <button name="browse">Browse</button>
</form>
```

The question is how do I distinguish if the user has entered a search query and wants to search the database, or has pressed the browse button to browse the database?

Do you need to change my HTML/Form, or is there any neat PHP trick to distinguish between the search or browse function?

Comment: The `form` has no submit button. How does the user submit a search query?

Comment: I might not be HTML standard, but it works fine when pressing the [ENTER] key after you've typed in your search query. I'm just a bit lazy, I didn't put a default submit button in the form.

Comment: @NateBarbettini — `<button name="browse">Browse</button>` is a submit button.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add another submit button for Browse:

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
  <button name="browse">Browse</button>
  <button name="search">Search</button>
  <input autofocus name="query" placeholder="Enter your search here..." type="search" />
</form>
```

---

Or, Make one form for each:

I prefer the two forms because I often embed additional information in hidden inputs or I can direct each form to a different script.  Two forms give more me flexibility.

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
  <button name="browse">Browse</button>
</form>
<form action="index.php" method="get">
  <input autofocus name="query" placeholder="Enter your search here..." type="search" />
  <button name="search">Search</button>
</form>
```

If you want the buttons in separate forms side by side you may have to add some CSS

```
form{display:inline;margin:0;padding:0;}
```

I put both two buttons in one form and two forms each with one button on the same page:

And cannot tell them apart

[image]

Comment: you dont need 2 forms, just 2 submits

Comment: You are correct.  There is no down side to having two forms.  There is no difference in layout with two forms or one form and two submits.  The two forms is more flexible as the two buttons do not have to be in the same form.  Also you can add hidden fields to each form with different values.

Comment: writing more than necessary is the downside

Comment: Yes if 45 bytes makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Fiddling with the two submit button as mentioned above. And I've come up with this solution:

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
  <input autofocus name="query" placeholder="Enter your search query here..." type="search" />
  <input hidden type="submit" />
  <button name="browse" value="true">Browse</button>
</form>
```

That accomplishes what I want. You can type in your search query and press [ENTER] key to search database, or you can click the Browse button to browse the database.